# Pass commands to Biblatex in Lyx via Latex Preamble (Errors)

Tags: biblatex, lyx

[For the following, I found an answer myself, but I didn't find the necessary extra step on any forums. Therefore, I shortly provide it in Q&A style.]

I have some custom formatting to tweak my `biblatex` settings that I want LyX to use (via `\DeclareFieldFormat`), but putting those in the Latex preamble (via *Document->Settings->LaTeX Preamble*) creates errors. (In my case, I want all titles to be Italic which makes using a footnote style and referring to titles and shorttitles within Text more legible.)

The problem seems that LyX loads `biblatex` just before `\begin{document}` as seen in exported LaTeX, but the custom LaTeX preamble before that. Tweaking `biblatex` before loading `biblatex` seems bad.

Errors are classic:

> ```
> Undefined control sequence
>
> Missing \begin{document}
>
> You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
> ```

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What works is »storing« the modifications in the preamble via (in my case)

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthand}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
}
```

Comment: Note that this is also what the LyX wiki suggests in point 5 of *Using Biblatex with LyX 2.3.0 and newer* in https://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex

Comment: Dangit - I didn't notice that under the heading of "transitioning from 2.2". My bad!

Comment: I edited the LyX wiki to make the need for `\AtBeginDocument` more prominent.

Comment: Looking at the edit by @moewe I am certain I wouldn't have missed the solution in the Wiki. So this question could be closed / removed if so desired.